# What is the size (in bytes) of String comparing with char?

Tags: arduino, variable-types

I'm facing the memory enough in arduino, so I decided that i need to change variable types. Thinking about it, I would like to know the size in bytes of *String* comparing with *char* (1byte).

I know that *String* is an object and *char* is a variable type.

Answer (score 1):

There are three member variables inside of `String` class:

```
char *buffer;           // the actual char array
unsigned int capacity;  // the array length minus one (for the '\0')
unsigned int len;       // the String length (not counting the '\0')
```

All of them are `2 bytes` wide (on `AVR` platform), so if you don't have anything in it, it might actually be just `6 bytes` total.

However, I suppose you do want something in it, so for single character you need another 2 bytes (one for that character and one for terminating `NUL` character).
And as the `buffer` is allocated dynamically, there must be stored something about this allocation either.

Reccomended reading: [The Evils of Arduino Strings](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)

On the other side C-strings are much more difficult to use but at least you have full control. You can create it on stack or heap (String class can use heap only).
String literals are much more tricky on the `AVR` platform as they are stored in program memory but also copied into the RAM to occupy the space you can't waste. More details on [Arduino - PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM) or [Nick Gammon's forum](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem) or [avr-libc pgmspace.h reference page](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html).

Comment: Wow! Nice! Yes, im developing as low level as possible... A lot of funtions and data logging. Im programming as C, btw. Thanks.